# Update a table based on another table with trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

What I´m trying to do is:

I have a table "emprestimo"
with the sytax like this:

| ID | User | Publicacao Id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |

I also have a table "publicacao" that is like this:

| ID | Emprestimos_total |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |

What I´m trying to do is when I insert an "emprestimo" for id 1, in the table "publicacao" the "Emprestimos_total" would go from "1" to "2".

I was thinking about using a trigger like this:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER update_qtq_emp
  AFTER INSERT ON emprestimo
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE publicacao
     SET Emprestimos_total = Emprestimos_total + 1
   where Id = NEW.Id;
END;
```

Is there any way to do this in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you create a view such as

```sql
CREATE [OR REPLACE] VIEW v_publicacao 
AS
    SELECT id, COUNT(id) AS Emprestimos_total
    FROM emprestimo
    GROUP BY id
```

and query from this just like querying from a table whenever needed.

There might exist wrong results if trigger is disabled by a reason for the current case, and no need to store a data, within another source, which is already computable.